# Allocating and freeing memory in a single kernel slower than Allocating in one then freeing in another

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda

**Background**

I had CUDA application in which I wanted to reproduce how I had improved performance.  I ended up writing the entire code over but could not reproduce the performance gains.  Then I noticed that I had a memory leak in the original code.  So I added the required delete, then my performance plummeted.

Now I understand memory allocation and deletion should have some overhead.  But I then did a test and I found out that if I allocate in one kernel and then perform the memory de-allocation in another I don't get the performance penalty.

I have some example code and output of the performance.  From the example you get on average a 2.64 speedup (ignoring the really strange first one).

In my real world example though I see a speedup of around 10.  For instance I have one that takes 45 minutes when I use two kernels, and 8 hours with one kernel.

**Question**

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

The only thing I can think of are these two cases:

1. There is a bug
2. delete does take a really long time

   - In the first kernel it waits for it to complete
   - In the second kernel it calls delete and returns right away.

**Setup**

*OS :*

Windows 7 64-bit

*nvcc --version :*

Built on Fri_Mar_14_19:30:01_PDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.0, V6.0.1

*Compiler Options :*

nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_35 forty_hours_debugging.cu

*---EDIT---*

*GPU :*

GTX 780

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

__device__ int *D_DATA[1000];

__global__ void MyAllocate(int size,bool perform_delete) {
    int *data;
    __shared__ int *t_data;

    if(threadIdx.x==0) {
        t_data = new int[size];
    }__syncthreads();

    if(t_data==NULL) return;

    D_DATA[blockIdx.x] = data= t_data;  

    memset(data,0,size);
    __syncthreads();

    for(int i = threadIdx.x;i < size; i+= blockDim.x) {
            data[i] = i * i + perform_delete * i;
    }__syncthreads();

    // If we should delete then do so, otherwise another kernel (hopefully) will
    if(threadIdx.x==0 && perform_delete) {
        delete data;
    }
}

__global__ void MyDelete() {
    delete D_DATA[blockIdx.x];
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {    

    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    float time;
    const std::string pre[2] = {"One Kernel ","Two Kernels "};  

    for(int size = 1000000; size < 1024000000; size *= 2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {

            cudaEventCreate(&start);
            cudaEventCreate(&stop);

            cudaEventRecord(start,0);
            MyAllocate<<<1000,128>>>(size,i==0);
            if(i!=0) {
                MyDelete<<<1000,1>>>();
            }
            cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
            cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
            cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
            std::cout << pre[i] << "Time : " << (time) << "ms" << std::endl;

            cudaEventDestroy(start);
            cudaEventDestroy(stop);
        }
        cudaDeviceReset();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Results**

```
One Kernel Time : 88.3073ms
Two Kernels Time : 88.3073ms

One Kernel Time : 0.109024ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.042912ms

One Kernel Time : 0.11184ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.042272ms

One Kernel Time : 0.1072ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.042688ms

One Kernel Time : 0.098464ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.042208ms

One Kernel Time : 0.103776ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.0432ms

One Kernel Time : 0.111776ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.04256ms

One Kernel Time : 0.114592ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.0424ms

One Kernel Time : 0.109888ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.042656ms

One Kernel Time : 0.119456ms
Two Kernels Time : 0.042336ms
```

Comment: Can someone explain why they marked this down?  So I can make sure I know what not to do in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a pretty important point, and that is that the size of the device heap (from which device `new` or `malloc` receive their allocations) [is *limited*](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#heap-memory-allocation).   The default limit is 8MB.  You can adjust this limit. (Read the documentation.)

Your first allocation just happens to fit under the 8MB limit (==4MB) and therefore the allocation (requested by a single threadblock) is succeeding.  Other threadblocks in that first launch are failing, and the remainder of your allocations are 8MB or larger, and are all failing.  So all that data is not indicating what you think.

I would recommend putting some kind of explicit notification out (`printf` or whatever) when this early exit happens:

```
if(t_data==NULL) return;
```

Here's a modified version of your example, fully worked with errors fixed.  Two kernel time doesn't seem to be any quicker than one kernel time:

```
$ cat t482.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__device__ int *D_DATA[1000];

__global__ void MyAllocate(int size,bool perform_delete) {
    int *data;
    __shared__ int *t_data;

    if(!threadIdx.x)
        t_data = new int[size];
    __syncthreads();

    if(t_data==NULL) {if(!threadIdx.x) printf("oops!\n"); return;}

    if(!threadIdx.x) D_DATA[blockIdx.x] = t_data;
    data = t_data;

    memset(data,0,size);
    __syncthreads();

    for(int i = threadIdx.x;i < size; i+= blockDim.x)
            data[i] = i * i + perform_delete * i;
    __syncthreads();

    // If we should delete then do so, otherwise another kernel (hopefully) will
    if((!threadIdx.x) && (perform_delete))
        delete data;

}

__global__ void MyDelete() {
    delete D_DATA[blockIdx.x];
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {

    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    float time;
    const std::string pre[2] = {"One Kernel ","Two Kernels "};

    for(int size = 1000000; size < 100000000; size *= 2) {
        cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 500000000);
        cudaCheckErrors("set limit fail");
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {

            cudaEventCreate(&start);
            cudaEventCreate(&stop);

            cudaEventRecord(start,0);
            MyAllocate<<<1,128>>>(size,i==0);
            if(i!=0) {
                MyDelete<<<1,1>>>();
            }
            cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
            cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
            cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
            std::cout << pre[i] << "Time : " << (time) << "ms" << std::endl;

            cudaEventDestroy(start);
            cudaEventDestroy(stop);
            cudaCheckErrors("some error");
        }
        cudaDeviceReset();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t482 t482.cu
$ ./t482
One Kernel Time : 139.846ms
Two Kernels Time : 139.37ms

One Kernel Time : 280.762ms
Two Kernels Time : 274.804ms

One Kernel Time : 559.386ms
Two Kernels Time : 549.536ms

One Kernel Time : 1101.04ms
Two Kernels Time : 1114.58ms

One Kernel Time : 2199.96ms
Two Kernels Time : 2229.1ms

One Kernel Time : 4397.82ms
Two Kernels Time : 4458.15ms

One Kernel Time : 8793.6ms
Two Kernels Time : 8916.23ms

$
```

Note that your `cudaDeviceReset()` resets the device limit as well, which is why it has to be placed at the right place in the proper loop.

Comment: You are correct.  I feel so dumb now.  I modified the if statement to also do a printf.  It never stops printing. Thanks for you help.